# Can one java process fetch ids of other java processes running on the same host?

Tags: java, profiling, instrumentation, pid

Is there a way to find which jvms are currently running, and get their PIDs?
e.g. when launching JVisualvm, it shows all local jvms. How can I do that?

**Background:** I'm working on an instrumentation project, and I would like to attach an agent to another (unknown) java process. The idea is to display all currently running java processes, and let the user choose a process from that list.
Thanks!

**[edit]** I do mean processes, not threads.

Comment: wouldnt it be better to let both communicate using sockets or pipes for example?

Comment: You could use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html). It comes with the JDK.

Comment: I think its NOT. Since OP wants to have list of processes currently running instead if threads in JVM.

Comment: You might need to use Runtime.exec() to run an external(OS) command for listing all the PID and probably filtering them. For doing that you can look at [this](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html). Would that work I'm not sure and it will depend what kind of information you can get from the PID listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Runtime` for that. This should give you a way ahead to proceed with.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND_TO_GET_PROCESS_DATA);
```

[Ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: thanks. got any idea about "COMMAND_TO_GET_PROCESS_DATA" you've mentioned? I want it to run on windows.

Comment: Not sure, but `tasklist` can do the trick.

Comment: Did this resolved your issue ?

Comment: not entirely. I have some running processes that does not appear in tasklist, but I admit I didn't try hard enough...

Comment: hmm may be but you need to login thru admin to see all process

Comment: took me a year to go back to that old project, and this solution is solid enough. Thanks!